# How to use BulkProcessor in synchronous processing?

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am trying to figure out how to use **BulkProcessor** [java-rest-high-document-bulk-processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html#java-rest-high-document-bulk-processor) during synchronous processing (`bulk` method) so that I could write something like this:

```kotlin
    val processor = BulkProcessor.builder(
        { request, _ ->
            client.bulk(
                request,
                RequestOptions.DEFAULT
            )
        })
```

Unfortunately, documentation only mentions async substitutes.

I know that BulkProcessor has **concurrentRequests** [BulkProcessor.Builder.setConcurrentRequests](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.0.1/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkProcessor.Builder.html#setConcurrentRequests-int-) property which I could set to **0** but is it enough to mimic synchronous behavior?

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do not use `BulkProcessor` then do a `BulkRequest` and use `client.bulk(request` like explain in the linked documentation ?

Comment: @ExploZe I mentioned BulkProcessor because it allows me to set things like bulkActions or BackoffPolicy (hence the question). Is it possible to set mentioned properties while using sync bulk method?